# How out-of-order/speculative execution influence timed profiling?

Tags: kernel, cpu, cpu-architecture

As modern CPU performs out-of-order and speculative execution, instructions are carried out completely out-of-order even speculatively.

How does this behavior influence timed profiling?

Consider the following case:

```
// #1
time1 = gettime()

// #2
loop for a few times {
  t *= 100
  t += 10
  t /= 20
}

// #3 
time2 = gettime()

// #4
record(time2 - time1)
```

As a result of out-of-order execution,

- time2 - time1 may be larger than the total time running three #2 lines, because #1 line involved instructions may be reordered after #3 lines', since time1 and t are separate memory locations and have no relation to each other.
- time2 - time1 may be smaller than the total time running three #2 lines, becase #4 involved instructions reordered before #3 involved instructions.

How much does this kind of reordering influence this kind of timed profiling?

Will speculative execution make much effort to record #3 to even before the start of the first time looping?

How to correctly and reliably profile #2 operations?

Comment: If you want to profile/time some piece of code, don't keep the profiling code in the same binary as the code you want to profile. And if you after accurate profiling information better to use a profiling tools out there. If you want just the time it spent on your code, in linux, use "time" before calling your binary.

Comment: @IsuruH But what is happening inside these tools you metioned? How could these tools deal with out of order execution problems?

Comment: Because you are using another tool to profile your code. Basically you won't have #1, #3 or #4 inside your code. We asking the profiler to profile #2. If #2 decides to execute out of order, still it will be code related to #2, nothing else.

Comment: Putting the code under test in a stand-alone static executable and profiling that works (e.g. with `perf stat`), but has quite a lot of startup overhead so you have to run it in a loop many times to hide that overhead, so it runs at least a couple hundred milliseconds.  But this always works because out-of-order execution can't happen across context switches; system calls (e.g. `syscall` and `sysret` on x86) flush the pipeline as well as switching from user to kernel mode.  You can get lower-overhead results by using a serializing instruction (like `cpuid` on x86) around the code under test.